# How can I quit a while loop in Objective C using scanf and a C character array string comparison?

Tags: while-loop, scanf

I am writing a simple test program to quit a while loop when the user enters EXIT:

```
char *userEntry;
while(userEntry != "EXIT")
{
  NSLog(@"Enter EXIT to quit");
  scanf("%s", &userEntry);
}
```

As is, the loop doesn't quit.

Could anyone explain to me what I need to do so make it work? 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing the address of the userEntry variable with that of the "EXIT" string constant. You need to compare their contents instead. Use `strcmp`, and read up on pointers.

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 problems,

1. You need to assign space to hold your string, just to declare *userEntry only creates a pointer. try writing it like this char userEntry[10];
2. you can't compare a pointer to a char array, try using strcmp... write it like this

if(0!=strcmp(userEntry, "EXIT"))
{
  scanf(...)
}

AsiQue